# How to check query_cache_type value on my server

Tags: php, mysql, query-cache

I have checked the status of query cache by using this query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE ‘%query_cache%’;` .  Likewise is there any query or command for checking the value of `query_cache_type`.  Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try any of these:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache_type';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| query_cache_type | ON    |
+------------------+-------+


SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_VARIABLES WHERE VARIABLE_NAME='query_cache_type';
+------------------+----------------+
| VARIABLE_NAME    | VARIABLE_VALUE |
+------------------+----------------+
| QUERY_CACHE_TYPE | ON             |
+------------------+----------------+


SELECT @@query_cache_type;
+--------------------+
| @@query_Cache_type |
+--------------------+
| ON                 |
+--------------------+

SELECT @@query_cache_type = 'ON' AS is_it_on;
+----------+
| is_it_on |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache_type';
```